# Find max( LCM(X1,X2...,Xn). If X1+X2.....+Xn = 13

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider positive integers $X_1,X_2....X_n$ such that $X_1+ X_2+ X_3 ... + X_n$ = 13 .**Where n is also a Variable varying from 1 to 13** Find the maximum value of $$LCM (X_1,X_2....X_n)$$
Basically I was solving a different problem and upon simplifying it translated to this problem. I tried Thinking when will it be maximum i.e the set has to contain maximum number of prime values. So I tried hit and trial to see values $n =4, X_1=2,X_2=1,X_3=7,X_4=3$ and
$n=3,X_1=5,X_2=7,X_3 =1$ But I am unable to Rigorously reason my way through the answer.
Original question :- **A man is shuffling a deck in a particular way again and again in the same exact way. We have to find the maximum number of shuffles after which the order of cards returns to original order.**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you sir.  Can you see if it  the question is properly structured now ?.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: I don't understand why this question in its present form is closed.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000793

Comment: @lhf's link implies the optimum is $\operatorname{LCM}(1,\,3,\,4,\,5)=60$.

Comment: @Ihf  . The answer indeed is 60 . Can you pls elaborate The solution I am unable to understand